# CSS: Partial ellipsis in variable text

Tags: css, sass, ellipsis

**Context**

I have text with variable length(responded from server). And requirement is like below

1. I have product name and unit.
2. Max line is 2 and ellipsis have to only applied to name, not unit.

[image]

It means that I consider length of unit, is it possible? I have ellipsis mixin that only consider max-lines like below.

```
@mixin overflowTextVertical($line) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $line;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

How can I use this existing mixin or is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your mixin accordingly. I can only think of these two methods though:

```css
.product__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 60px 20px 10px;
}

.product__item h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.product__item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 37px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__item">
  <h1>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglon glonglonglongProductNameNa</h1>
  <h3>(unit)</h3>
</div>
```

Or you could try this, event though I don't recommend using this approach.

```css
.product__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.product__item h1 {
  position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 25px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
}
.product__item h3 {
      font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.product__item h3:after {
  content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 60px 0 4px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -23px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__item">
  <h1>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglon glonglonglongProductNameNa</h1>
  <h3>(unit)</h3>
</div>

<div class="product__item">
  <h1>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglon glonglonglongProductNameNa</h1>
  <h3>(unit)</h3>
</div>
```